# Apache Camel returns JSON with escape characters

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, cxf, dsl

I have a rest service in camel, which consults another SOAP service, the SOAP response makes a POJO unmarshal and then I make the marshal to a JSON object. In console everything is perfect, but in the output of the service I see string with escape characters or an array of byte

I tried to return a JSONObject, Strings, Byte [] but there is something I am missing along the way, I think it will be a problem with the serialization of json

```
     JacksonDataFormat jacksonDataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat();
     jacksonDataFormat.setPrettyPrint(true);

     from("direct:spliting")
        .log("Start Spliting")
        .setBody(xPath)
        .log("Split: ${body}")
        .unmarshal(new CustomUnmarshall())
        .marshal(jacksonDataFormat)
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .setHeader("Content-Type", simple("application/json"))
        .removeHeader("ResponseContext")
        .log("Marshal: ${body}")
        .end();
```

In console, the result is OK:

```
{"def":null,"v":{"a":4877,"c":1},"sa":[{"kv":[{"ar":null,"v":["C000000002"],"k":"campaignCode"},{"ar":null,"v":["0.75"],"k":"propension"},{"ar":null,"v":["ATM"],"k":"canal"}, ...
```

But in response in postman is:

```
"{\r\n  \"sa\" : [ {\r\n    \"kv\" : [ {\r\n      \"k\" : \"campaignCode\",\r\n      \"v\" : [ \"C000000001\" ],\r\n      \"ar\" : null\r\n    }, {\r\n      \"k\" : \"propension\",\r\n      \"v\" : [ \"0.5\" ],\r\n      \"ar\" : null\r\n    }, {\r\n      \"k\" : \"canal\",\r\n      \"v\" : [ \"Sucursal\" ],\r\n      \"ar\" : null\r\n    }, {\r\n      \"k\" : \"offerCode\",\r\n
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting the bindingMode option to "off" fixes escaping the JSON string when served via camel-rest. Maybe this will help(the example does not show how the data is served to Postman).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a problem here. The postman output is a JSON marshalled as String. And this is what you do in your route.

Since you have `setPrettyPrint(true)` you have lots of CR-LF (line separators) in your String. You can get rid of them if you disable pretty print.

Check out this [Camel UnitTest](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jackson/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/jackson/JacksonMarshalTest.java) for Jackson marshal/unmarshal with and without pretty print to compare the format with your result.

You also get such JSON-Strings (with escaped double-quotes etc) when you use the Jackson method

```
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(yourJson);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I try but I get this response, It is a string and not an json object: https://i.ibb.co/cXgsh9m/Captura.png

Comment: Well, you convert it to a String with `.convertBodyTo(String.class)` so it seems to be obvious that you get a String. Or am I misunderstanding something?